# Deleting key:value pairs in a list with value over a certain threshold

Tags: python, list, key-value, threshold

I´m stuck (as usual) and can't find a working solution om my problem. I´m new into this.

I have a list like myList `{'00:00': 24.3, '01:00': 31.22, '02:00': 30.69, '03:00': 30.16, '04:00': 31.04, '05:00': **153.48**, '06:00': **140.48**, '07:00': **289.78**}` and want to get rid of all key/values in the list if the value is over a certain threshold ex 100.00 (marked above).

The list I want back would be like: newList `{'00:00': 24.3, '01:00': 31.22, '02:00': 30.69, '03:00': 30.16, '04:00': 31.04}`

How do I code it?

Comment: Since you're learning - You're working with `dict`, not `list`. Have you tried any code? And if so, please show it. Do you have an inkling of how to start, in terms of the logic?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a list but a dictionary.

```
d = {'00:00': 24.3, '01:00': 31.22, '02:00': 30.69, '03:00': 30.16, '04:00': 31.04, '05:00': 153.48, '06:00': 140.48, '07:00': 289.78}
```

Use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v < 100}
```

Output:

```
{'00:00': 24.3, '01:00': 31.22, '02:00': 30.69, '03:00': 30.16, '04:00': 31.04}
```